# Fatal Error when trying to create new 'Session' object on an Oreo device

Tags: java, android, session, fatal-error, opentok

I have a project that works fine on android 6.0, but when I run it on Android 8.0 it crushes on the method:

```
try
{
    mSession = new Session(mContext, api_key, session_id);  // Crush Here!
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();  // Never Gets to the catch! why ??!
}
```

and inside it, on the method:

```
this.init(cacertFile, context, hwdecoding, apiKey, sessionId, model, apiLevel);
```

in the 'Session.class' file.

I gave needed permissions for read/write to the device internal storage.

What can be the problem?

Here is some data that I collected that may help:

---

```
 * * * Crush on the "new Session(...)" method:
 =============================================

private void sessionConnect(String api_key, String session_id, String token)
{
    if (mSession == null) 
    {
        try
        {
            mSession = new Session(mContext, api_key, session_id);  // Crush Here!
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();  // Never Gets to the catch! Why ???
        }

            mSession.setSessionListener(this);
            mSession.setConnectionListener(this);
            mSession.setSignalListener(this);
            mSession.connect(token);
        }
    }

 * * * Debug params just before the crush:
 =========================================


    this = {OpenTokStreamer@5445} 
    api_key = "45276332"
    session_id = "1_MX40NTI3NjMzMn5-MTU0MTY2MzEwNjMwMH5mbVZiWGdYN0tETVNWeEZkOE9KVmRKYzd-fg"
    token = "T1==cGFydG5lcl9pZD00NTI3NjMzMiZzaWc9MGQ3ZThlYjFmYzcyZGUzMGY1NDBkM2NjNGMwZDQ2YTIzOWUwMmZiZTpzZXNzaW9uX2lkPTFfTVg0ME5USTNOak16TW41LU1UVTBNVFkyTXpFd05qTXdNSDVtYlZaaVdHZFlOMHRFVFZOV2VFWmtPRTlLVm1SS1l6ZC1mZyZjcmVhdGVfdGltZT0xNTQxNjkxMjcyJm5vbmNlPTAuNTkwMzE0MjA5NDYxMjEyMiZyb2xlPW1vZGVyYXRvciZleHBpcmVfdGltZT0xNTQxNzc3Njcy"
    mSession = null
    mContext = {Application@5449} 
     mActivityLifecycleCallbacks = {ArrayList@5453}  size = 0
     mAssistCallbacks = null
     mComponentCallbacks = {ArrayList@5454}  size = 0
     mFlipfont = 0
     mLoadedApk = {LoadedApk@5455} 
     mBase = {ContextImpl@5456} 
     shadow$_klass_ = {Class@1873} "class android.app.Application"
     shadow$_monitor_ = -2030428451

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 * * * If I do Step-Into, then I can see that it crush on the method:
 ====================================================================

    this.init(cacertFile, context, hwdecoding, apiKey, sessionId, model, apiLevel);


 * * * Debug params just before the crush:
 =========================================


    this = {Session@5445} 
    context = {Application@5441} 
    apiKey = "45276332"
    sessionId = "1_MX40NTI3NjMzMn5-MTU0MTY2MzEwNjMwMH5mbVZiWGdYN0tETVNWeEZkOE9KVmRKYzd-fg"
    sessionOptions = {Session$DefaultSessionOptions@5449} 
    cacertFile = "/data/user/0/com.myVideoApp/cache/.ca-cert.pem"
    hwdecoding = false
    model = 0
    apiLevel = 26


---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 * * * Logcat a little before and after the Fatal crush:
 =======================================================

 (Search "beginning of crash")

2018-11-08 17:38:40.389 9757-9803/com.myVideoApp D/InitIP: D05 384
2018-11-08 17:38:40.389 9757-9803/com.myVideoApp D/InitIP: D06 288
2018-11-08 17:38:40.392 9757-9793/com.myVideoApp D/RenderScript: [RS-DIAG] Launching CPU script : slot(0)
2018-11-08 17:38:40.420 9757-9793/com.myVideoApp D/RenderScript: [RS-DIAG] Invoking CPU script : slot(0)
2018-11-08 17:38:40.421 9757-9793/com.myVideoApp D/RenderScript: [RS-DIAG] Launching CPU script : slot(0)
2018-11-08 17:38:40.428 9757-9803/com.myVideoApp D/onRawReceived: C05 
2018-11-08 17:38:40.503 9757-9803/com.myVideoApp D/onRawReceived: C02 
2018-11-08 17:38:40.503 9757-9803/com.myVideoApp D/onRawReceived: C03 221696
2018-11-08 17:38:40.503 9757-9803/com.myVideoApp D/InitIP: D05 384
2018-11-08 17:38:40.503 9757-9803/com.myVideoApp D/InitIP: D06 288
2018-11-08 17:38:40.509 9757-9793/com.myVideoApp D/RenderScript: [RS-DIAG] Launching CPU script : slot(0)
2018-11-08 17:38:40.558 9757-9793/com.myVideoApp D/RenderScript: [RS-DIAG] Invoking CPU script : slot(0)
2018-11-08 17:38:40.558 9757-9793/com.myVideoApp D/RenderScript: [RS-DIAG] Launching CPU script : slot(0)
2018-11-08 17:38:40.568 9757-9803/com.myVideoApp D/onRawReceived: C05 
2018-11-08 17:38:40.597 9757-9757/com.myVideoApp D/opentok-session: HW decoding enabled? : false
2018-11-08 17:38:40.598 9757-9757/com.myVideoApp D/opentok-audiodevicemanager: AUDIO_DEVICE creating default device
2018-11-08 17:38:40.616 9757-9803/com.myVideoApp D/onRawReceived: C02 
2018-11-08 17:38:40.616 9757-9803/com.myVideoApp D/onRawReceived: C03 221696
2018-11-08 17:38:40.617 9757-9803/com.myVideoApp D/InitIP: D05 384
2018-11-08 17:38:40.617 9757-9803/com.myVideoApp D/InitIP: D06 288
2018-11-08 17:38:40.619 9757-9793/com.myVideoApp D/RenderScript: [RS-DIAG] Launching CPU script : slot(0)
2018-11-08 17:38:40.640 3650-4374/? D/ActivityManager: The following uid has registered to recieve broadcast for proxy related updates 10180
2018-11-08 17:38:40.640 9757-9793/com.myVideoApp D/RenderScript: [RS-DIAG] Invoking CPU script : slot(0)

    --------- beginning of system
2018-11-08 17:38:40.640 3650-4374/? W/ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:971 com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.requestKnoxVpnToSendProxyBroadcast:29479 com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.registerReceiver:23200 android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact:176 com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact:3862 
2018-11-08 17:38:40.641 9757-9793/com.myVideoApp D/RenderScript: [RS-DIAG] Launching CPU script : slot(0)
2018-11-08 17:38:40.643 3650-3650/? D/KnoxVpnEngineService: Vpn Receiver : com.samsung.android.knox.intent.action.VPN_PROXY_BROADCAST_INTERNAL
2018-11-08 17:38:40.643 9757-9757/com.myVideoApp D/JVM: JVM::Initialize@[tid=9757]
2018-11-08 17:38:40.643 9757-9757/com.myVideoApp D/JVM: JVM::JVM@[tid=9757]
2018-11-08 17:38:40.643 3650-3813/? I/KnoxVpnEngineService: vpn handle : Message received
2018-11-08 17:38:40.644 9757-9757/com.myVideoApp D/opentok: *********************** ANDROID SDK android-2.9.0 ********************************
2018-11-08 17:38:40.644 9757-9757/com.myVideoApp D/opentok: **** Lib built on Aug 30 2016 at 01:09:53
2018-11-08 17:38:40.644 9757-9757/com.myVideoApp D/opentok: **** OpenTok Android SDK : fd74797c714c9b83f48c623283a0cd2d6a83e27e
2018-11-08 17:38:40.644 9757-9757/com.myVideoApp D/opentok: **** OpenTok OTKIT : bde819521d6220c6f04ff831d93d5d9271d96227
2018-11-08 17:38:40.644 9757-9757/com.myVideoApp D/opentok: **** WEBRTC REVISION : 52-001 -ca7fe7ea0257ae5e4318549abbe7c0f79063865e-Release-02349d7ac3b59c7017d28f86b599f60fa4f1f498
2018-11-08 17:38:40.645 9757-9757/com.myVideoApp D/opentok: **** Copyright 2016 TokBox, Inc.
2018-11-08 17:38:40.645 9757-9757/com.myVideoApp D/opentok: **** Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0
2018-11-08 17:38:40.645 9757-9757/com.myVideoApp D/opentok: ************************************************************************
2018-11-08 17:38:40.646 3271-3271/? E/audit: type=1400 audit(1541691520.638:161): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=9757 comm="com.myVideoApp" name="stat" dev="proc" ino=4026534927 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:proc_stat:s0 tclass=file permissive=0 SEPF_SM-G930F_8.0.0_0011 audit_filtered


    --------- beginning of crash
2018-11-08 17:38:40.648 9757-9757/com.myVideoApp A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xc in tid 9757 (com.myVideoApp)
2018-11-08 17:38:40.648 9757-9803/com.myVideoApp D/onRawReceived: C05 
2018-11-08 17:38:40.734 3271-3271/? E/audit: type=1400 audit(1541691520.728:162): avc:  denied  { search } for  pid=9918 comm="crash_dump32" name="com.myVideoApp" dev="dm-1" ino=460366 scontext=u:r:crash_dump:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0 SEPF_SM-G930F_8.0.0_0011 audit_filtered
2018-11-08 17:38:40.735 3271-3271/? I/chatty: uid=1999(audit) /system/bin/auditd identical 1 line
2018-11-08 17:38:40.736 3271-3271/? E/audit: type=1400 audit(1541691520.728:164): avc:  denied  { search } for  pid=9918 comm="crash_dump32" name="com.myVideoApp" dev="dm-1" ino=460366 scontext=u:r:crash_dump:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0 SEPF_SM-G930F_8.0.0_0011 audit_filtered
2018-11-08 17:38:40.775 9918-9918/? I/crash_dump32: obtaining output fd from tombstoned
2018-11-08 17:38:40.777 3326-3326/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: received crash request for pid 9757
2018-11-08 17:38:40.780 9918-9918/? I/crash_dump32: performing dump of process 9757 (target tid = 9757)
2018-11-08 17:38:40.782 9918-9918/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
2018-11-08 17:38:40.782 9918-9918/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'samsung/heroltexx/herolte:8.0.0/R16NW/G930FXXU2ERGE:user/release-keys'
2018-11-08 17:38:40.782 9918-9918/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '8'
2018-11-08 17:38:40.782 9918-9918/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm'
2018-11-08 17:38:40.782 9918-9918/? A/DEBUG: pid: 9757, tid: 9757, name: com.myVideoApp  >>> com.myVideoApp <<<
2018-11-08 17:38:40.782 9918-9918/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xc
2018-11-08 17:38:40.782 9918-9918/? A/DEBUG: Cause: null pointer dereference
2018-11-08 17:38:40.782 9918-9918/? A/DEBUG:     r0 00000000  r1 059c7d66  r2 00000004  r3 00000000
2018-11-08 17:38:40.782 9918-9918/? A/DEBUG:     r4 00000000  r5 ffb0c598  r6 cc06e1a8  r7 ffb0ca88
2018-11-08 17:38:40.783 9918-9918/? A/DEBUG:     r8 cbf25fd8  r9 cc06e1a8  sl f0ef1220  fp f060400c
2018-11-08 17:38:40.783 9918-9918/? A/DEBUG:     ip cc04ab68  sp ffb0c530  lr cbb7a64c  pc f0eac098  cpsr 600f0030
2018-11-08 17:38:40.785 9918-9918/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
2018-11-08 17:38:40.785 9918-9918/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 00052098  /system/lib/libc.so (fclose+3)
2018-11-08 17:38:40.785 9918-9918/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 0005b648  /data/app/com.myVideoApp-9RMYld3ULGhDFy081B9XSw==/lib/arm/libopentok.so
2018-11-08 17:38:40.785 9918-9918/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 0005d19c  /data/app/com.myVideoApp-9RMYld3ULGhDFy081B9XSw==/lib/arm/libopentok.so (Java_com_opentok_android_Session_init+4452)
2018-11-08 17:38:40.786 9918-9918/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 00030e25  /data/app/com.myVideoApp-9RMYld3ULGhDFy081B9XSw==/oat/arm/base.odex (offset 0x22000)
2018-11-08 17:38:41.421 3326-3326/? E//system/bin/tombstoned: Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones//tombstone_09
2018-11-08 17:38:41.432 3650-9919/? W/ActivityManager: crash : com.myVideoApp,0
2018-11-08 17:38:41.433 3650-9919/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.myVideoApp/.MainActivity
2018-11-08 17:38:41.433 3650-9919/? W/MultiScreenManagerService: moveTaskBackToDisplayIfNeeded(): root activity or app is null, task=TaskRecord{2f01a69d0 #43 A=com.myVideoApp U=0 StackId=1 sz=1}, rootActivity=null
2018-11-08 17:38:41.433 3650-3650/? D/MdnieScenarioControlService: Listener Real Multi Window State : true
2018-11-08 17:38:41.437 3650-3675/? I/BootReceiver: Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_09 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
2018-11-08 17:38:41.443 3650-3670/? I/ActivityManager: Showing crash dialog for package com.myVideoApp u0
2018-11-08 17:38:41.465 3650-3670/? D/ScrollView: initGoToTop
2018-11-08 17:38:41.529 3650-3669/? D/CustomFrequencyManagerService: acquireDVFSLockLocked : type : DVFS_MIN_LIMIT  frequency : 2600000  uid : 1000  pid : 3650  pkgName : AMS_APP_HOME@CPU_MIN@9
2018-11-08 17:38:41.531 3650-3669/? D/ActivityManagerPerformance: AMP_acquire() HOME
2018-11-08 17:38:41.532 3190-3190/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/9757/oom_score_adj; errno=22
2018-11-08 17:38:41.535 3650-3668/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2018-11-08 17:38:41.535 3650-3668/? W/android.os.Debug: failed to get memory consumption info: -1
2018-11-08 17:38:41.535 9428-9428/? I/DMT-SMReceiver: Received : com.samsung.android.sm.ACTION_ERROR
2018-11-08 17:38:41.536 9428-9428/? W/ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.startService:1483 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:663 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:663 com.samsung.android.sm.common.SmartManagerReceiver.a:240 com.samsung.android.sm.common.SmartManagerReceiver.onReceive:119 
2018-11-08 17:38:41.537 3650-3670/? E/PhoneWindow_APM :: isCalledPackage return false
2018-11-08 17:38:41.538 4046-4059/? D/SystemServicesProxy: updateOverviewLastStackActiveTimeAsync: newTime=1541691521433
2018-11-08 17:38:41.538 3650-4374/? D/SecContentProvider: query(), uri = 17 selection = isSettingsChangesAllowed
2018-11-08 17:38:41.540 3650-4374/? D/SecContentProvider: called from android.uid.systemui:10040
2018-11-08 17:38:41.540 3650-3676/? V/MARsPolicyManager: handelAlertToastWindowStarted pkgName = android, userId = 0
2018-11-08 17:38:41.541 4046-4199/? D/SystemServicesProxy: updateOverviewLastStackActiveTimeAsync: done.
2018-11-08 17:38:41.542 3650-3670/? D/InputDispatcher: Focus left window: 9757
2018-11-08 17:38:41.542 3650-3670/? D/InputDispatcher: Focus entered window: 3650
2018-11-08 17:38:41.542 3650-3670/? V/WindowManager: rotationForOrientationLw(orient=-1, last=0); user=0  sensorRotation=-1 mLidState=-1 mDockMode=0 mHdmiPlugged=false
2018-11-08 17:38:41.542 3650-3670/? D/ViewRootImpl@e7a2b50[myVideoApp]: setView = DecorView@143876f[myVideoApp] TM=true MM=false
2018-11-08 17:38:41.542 3650-3670/? W/Looper: Dispatch took 103ms on android.ui, h=Handler (com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$UiHandler) {b74cc31} cb=null msg=1
2018-11-08 17:38:41.544 3650-6788/? D/GamePkgDataHelper: getGamePkgDataIncServer(). com.sec.android.app.launcher
2018-11-08 17:38:41.545 4317-4330/? D/ForegroundUtils: could not check pending caller
2018-11-08 17:38:41.545 3650-6788/? D/GameManagerService: identifyGamePackage. com.sec.android.app.launcher
2018-11-08 17:38:41.545 3650-6788/? D/GamePkgDataHelper: getGamePkgData(). com.sec.android.app.launcher
2018-11-08 17:38:41.546 3650-6788/? D/GameManagerService: identifyGamePackage. com.sec.android.app.launcher
2018-11-08 17:38:41.546 3650-6788/? D/GamePkgDataHelper: getGamePkgData(). com.sec.android.app.launcher
2018-11-08 17:38:41.547 3650-6788/? D/TelephonyManager: getAllCellInfo : Caller (PID / UID / TID): 3650 / 1000 / 6788
2018-11-08 17:38:41.551 3650-3670/? D/ViewRootImpl@e7a2b50[myVideoApp]: dispatchAttachedToWindow
2018-11-08 17:38:41.552 3650-3670/? V/WindowManager: Relayout Window{3170149 u0 Application Error: com.myVideoApp}: viewVisibility=0 req=1015x442 WM.LayoutParams{(0,0)(wrapxwrap) gr=#11 sim=#120 ty=2003 fl=#1820002 pfl=0x110 fmt=-3 wanim=0x10302ec surfaceInsets=Rect(6, 6 - 6, 6) needsMenuKey=2 colorMode=0 naviIconColor=0}
2018-11-08 17:38:41.554 3191-3191/? I/SurfaceFlinger: id=233 createSurf (1027x454),1 flag=4, Application Error: com.myVideoApp#0
2018-11-08 17:38:41.555 3650-3670/? V/Surface: sf_framedrop debug : 0x4f4c, game : false, logging : 0
2018-11-08 17:38:41.557 3650-3670/? D/ViewRootImpl@e7a2b50[myVideoApp]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][0,0] new=[32,775][1047,1217] result=0x7 surface={valid=true 506706321408} changed=true
2018-11-08 17:38:41.557 3650-4031/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2018-11-08 17:38:41.557 3650-4031/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 2
2018-11-08 17:38:41.560 3650-3670/? D/WindowManager: set systemUiVisibility : systemUiFlags= 0x408 fullscreenStackSysUiFlags= 0x0
2018-11-08 17:38:41.560 3650-3670/? D/ViewRootImpl@e7a2b50[myVideoApp]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
2018-11-08 17:38:41.560 9428-9922/? V/CrashedAppLogging: isMasterSwitchOff : false
```

---

Comment: Did you find the solution to this issue. I'm also facing the same problem. And I'm using the latest version of the sdk.

Comment: Not yet, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

TokBox Developer Evangelist here.

It looks like you're using an unsupported version of the OpenTok Android SDK. Please upgrade to latest(v2.15.0) OpenTok Android SDK.

To find out more about supported client SDKs, please check out the following links:

- https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/android/release-notes.html
- https://support.tokbox.com/hc/en-us/articles/204423250-What-versions-of-the-OpenTok-Client-SDKs-are-currently-supported-

Comment: Hi, I updated to OpenTok v2.15.0 but I still having the same problem. The application crush in Android 8.0 on the command "mSession = new Session.Builder(this, API_KEY, SESSION_ID).build();", I also tried an OpenTok example code from their official site, that use the exact same command with the exact same inputs and it runs OK. How can I detect the cause of this problem? Any try-catch that I can use for this command?

Comment: Could you please file an issue here https://github.com/opentok/opentok-android-sdk-samples/issues? It might be a better place to debug :D

Comment: Hi, is there any solution found for this problem ? Same happened when I upgraded my android OS to Oreo .

Comment: I updated the library version to 2.15 , it worked for me ........thanks